# Java Array Subtraction

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to make a method that takes as argument a multi dimensional array of integers and does the following:

- Checks if the number of rows and columns are odd, otherwise returns 0.
- If the array is odd, then the method returns the sum of the terms of the
  middle line, minus those in the middle column.

**For example :**

```
2  4  6

9  10 17

1  6  18
```

This exemple should return : `(9 + 10 + 17) − (4 + 10 + 6) = 36 − 20 = 16`

This is what I did so far :

```
static int [][] sub(int i , int j) {

    if (i%2 == 0 || j%2 == 0) 
    return 0;

    else
    int[][] tab = new int[i][j];

    // Create array with values from 0 to 99 randomly
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++) {
             tab[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 99);
         }
     }
}
```

After that, I don't really know what to do.. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: Hello and welcome. Is this homework?

Comment: Java does not support *function*s.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - what do you mean?

Comment: @ScaryWombat We have methods :p

Comment: I think you have missed that your method should expect one argument which contains a 2 dimensional array, not creating it and returning it?

Comment: well an algorithm if you prefer

Comment: @ScaryWombat And of course I hope we won't dig into that lambdas support functional programming.

Comment: You're not doing what you were told. You shall write a method that accepts a 2 dimensional array and do sth. with the values inside. What you are doing ist creating a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: From the example it seems you already understand loops. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @PaulJanssens i don't know how to summon the array entries.

Comment: I think you can do this by your own. You already understabd loops and have the knowledge about parameters.

Comment: @RedaLihuak You can add entries with + ? :D

Comment: The best part is writing code for this kind of requests and never get an "Answer is useful" or being chosen as final answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this

```
static int sub(int i , int j) {
    int result;
    int[][] tab = new int[i][j];
    if (i % 2 == 0 || j % 2 == 0) {
        result = 0;
    }
    else {
        // Create array with values from 0 to 99 randomly
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < j; l++) {
                tab[k][l] =(int)(Math.random()*99);
            }
        }
        int horizontalSum = 0;
        int verticalSum = 0;

        for(int k = 0; k<i; k++){
            horizontalSum+=tab[(i/2)][k];
        }
        for(int l = 0; l<j; l++){
            verticalSum += tab[l][(j/2)];
        }
        result = horizontalSum-verticalSum;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Good luck on your homework.  -_-

Answer (score 0):

Your method takes two integeres as parameters, not a two dimensional array. Instead, it returns a two dimensional array when it should just return an int.

In fact this:

```
static int [][] sub(int i , int j) {

    if (i%2 == 0 || j%2 == 0) 
    return 0;
           ^
```

is a compile-time error. You declated to return a two dimensional integer array, but you are just returning an integer.

I think your method should look like this:

```
static int sub(int[][] array)
{
    if (array.length % 2 == 0) return 0;
    for (int[] x : array)
    {
        if (x.length % 2 == 0) return 0;
    }


    int result = 0;
    int middle = array.length / 2;

    for (int i : array[middle])
    {
        result += i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array[middle].length; i++)
    {
        result -= array[i][middle];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This wont work. array.length returns an integer, not a float or double. So for example, if you do 5/2, it will return 2, not 2.5. You should add 1, not 0.5.

Comment: @EmreAcar You're right, my +0.5 is useless, but it does not break the method as arrays start with 0 and I don't even need to add 1. I updated my answer.